# Adding a vertical scroll bar to a wpf Grid while keeping the header line fixed

Tags: wpf

I am trying to add a vertical scrollbar to a  in WPF. I tried adding the grid into a  component which works but then the whole grid scrolls and the header row scrolls as well. I tried without the  but then didn't find a VerticalScroll property for the  control.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Pat

Comment: By grid. Do you mean datagrid or grid? Because the body of a datagrid has a scrollviewer in it. If you mean grid then please show us a minimal example shows us what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
//Put the content that you want scrollable here
            <Grid>
                
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Not enough information really maybe post your code?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a comment rather than an answer. Please expand on what you mean.

Comment: That's a good point! sorry I'm a bit new on here will post my reply's correctly in future.